# Unknown DataBinding Class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-databinding

I am newbie to DataBinding in Android and learning it to my own. I have just enabled the DataBinding in my App Gradle File in the Android Tag as:

```
    dataBinding{
        enabled=true
    }
```

---

My XML is setup like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

---

And my Activity Looks like:

---

The problem is that the **ActivityMainBinding Class is unknown** to Android Studio. I don't know why is this happening. As I had clean, re-build make the project and everything doesn't help me out!

I am attaching an [screen shot][1] too, looking at the screenshot you can find that the **ActivityMainBinding** is highlighted in **RED COLOR**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was totally strange because Its ANDROID STUDIO!

What I done is just changed the name of the **activity_main.xml** to **activity_main_.xml** then I make the project!

After Making the project, I reverted back to the old name i.e activity_main.xml and it works like a charm. Don't know but it works really because this **GooF Android Studio** doesn't even ever makes any sense!

Comment: Are you sure Pallavi's answer is not right? If no accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

It will only be named `ActivityMainBinding` if your layout is named `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: My layout is activity_main.xml so what should I do with the binding class?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using `<layout>` attribute in content_main.xml. So your binding class name will be ContentMainBinding.

Also you need to set R.layout.content_main to DataBindingUtils class.

OR

Just add `<layout>` in activity_main.xml and remove from content_main.xml and keep rest of code as it is. Just rebuild the project.